# set a container as a proxy server for outline server container

Tags: docker

The weird thing I'm doing is running outline serve in a container with the usual script from the outline manager GUI gives us and a proxy server in another container that listens on port 1080. I want all of my clients' traffic that connects to the outline to go through the proxy container. I set the all_proxy env on the outline container and it works on the container itself (I test a curl on the outline container cli) but the client's traffic doesn't go through that proxy.

is there any docker network solution or outline option for doing this?

Comment: We would greatly appreciate it if you could rework your query to ensure that we can comprehend the topic at hand. Furthermore, please clarify the business-related inquiry or issue at hand. It would be helpful for you to read: [ask]